# How to place 4 figures side by side in Overleaf

Tags: formatting, subfig

I'm trying to plot 4 figures like in the picture in overleaf. I did it in Latex, copy and pasted it to Overleaf, but it won't work.
[image: Example]

Here is my code from Latex:

```
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture1}
     \caption{..}
     \label{..}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture2}
     \caption{..}
     \label{..}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture3}
     \caption{..}
     \label{..}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture4}
     \caption{..}
     \label{..}
 \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption for all 4 Figures}
    \label{Label}
\end{figure}
```

Here are the warnings I get:

l.139      \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'. (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number, look up` weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

l.139      \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.49\textwidth}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Overleaf is a platform that lets you compile LaTeX code. Please clarify what you mean by "I did it in Latex and it worked but not in Overleaf".  Please also state whether you got warning and/or error messages when you tried to compile your document on the Overleaf platform.

Comment: If I prefix `\documentclass[demo]{article} \usepackage{graphicx,subcaption} \begin{document}` and affix `\end{document}` to your code in order to make it minimally compilable, your code indeed compiles just fine. Thus, do please more specific about the problems you're encountering when trying to compile your document on the Overleaf platform. Incidentally, when I wrote that your code "compiles just fine", I didn't mean to say that the code can't be improved. For instance, all five `\centering` instructions are redundant and could (should?) be omitted.

Comment: I added the warnings I get while compiling.

Comment: So you're getting *warning* messages: the `h` placement specifier for `subfigure` environments isn't recognized by LaTeX. The recognized placement specifiers are `t`, `c`, and `b` -- short for top, center, and bottom; `c` is the default. In the case of your code, just omit all four instances of `[h]`. Let me assure you  that your LaTeX distribution must have been generating the exact same warning messages; however, for some reason (do you maybe use TeXstudio??) you just didn't notice them until now, i.e., until you switched to Overleaf.

Comment: Your subfigure environments are to wide. Reduce them to `0.24\textwidth` .

Comment: @Zarko - Actually, the width of the `subfigure` environments is *not* a problem, as LaTeX silently replaces the second of three `\hfill` directives with a line break. (I wholeheartedly agree, though, that it would be better if the OP replaced the second instance of `\hfill` with an all-blank line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code compile without warning messages while also removing redundant code, I suggest you

- remove all four instances of `[h]` after `\begin{subfigure}` (as `h` is not a valid placement specifier);
- remove all five instances of `\centering` (as they are redundant);
- replace the second of three `\hfill` directives with an all-blank line (to be more up front about the fact that a line break is needed), followed by inserting `\medskip` or `\bigskip` (in order to create more of a visual separation between the captions that pertain to the upper two figures and the lower two images).

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}  % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture1}
     \caption{\dots}
     \label{fig:a}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture2}
     \caption{\dots}
     \label{fig:b}
 \end{subfigure}
 
 \medskip
 \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture3}
     \caption{\dots}
     \label{fig:c}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
 \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Picture4}
     \caption{\dots}
     \label{fig:d}
 \end{subfigure}

 \caption{Caption for all 4 figures}
 \label{Label}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for not making it clear what I needed. Yes, you were right I used TexStudio!

Comment: @MB33 - You're most welcome. Overall, TeXstudio is a very nice piece of software. It's therefore doubly unfortunate that TeXstudio does an exceedingly good job of hiding warning and error messages from users.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear, what is your problem. For example, the following MWE compile fine locally (using MiKTeX) as well on Overleaf. IN it I use your code fragment in which I made the following changes:

- remove all `\centering` commands
- define images width centrally by use keywords `Gin`
- reduce width of `subfigure` to `0.24\textwidth`
- change position option to `[t]` (however it works well also with `h`, which in your case hasn't sense)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture1}
         \caption{..}
         \label{..}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture2}
         \caption{..}
         \label{..}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture3}
         \caption{..}
         \label{..}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
         \centering
         \includegraphics{example-image-duck}%{Picture4}
         \caption{..}
         \label{..}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Caption for all 4 Figures}
        \label{Label}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(gray thick lines are page borders)